# Is this prior art or not? When a CCA-NC license precedes?

Tags: prior-art, prior

In reference to the patent: [US20140120196](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140120196)

Isn't is called prior art when a design presented under Creative Commons - Attribution - Non-Commercial license is patented?
Even the youtube video of inventor satoer predates this patent with more then a year
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsNm0UfQsyQ

Answer (score 1):

Without going into all the intricacies, prior art is anything that is made available to the public before the priority date. It doesn't really matter what licence it is under when it is released.

The patent you mention has a priority date of 29 October 2012. Assuming there were no changes between the priority filing and the actual filing, anything published before 29 October 2012 would be prior art.

The YouTube video you linked to appears to have been published on 1 October 2013, and so would likely not be prior art (putting aside whether videos could be prior art at all).